# Question from parabola

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

For the parabola y²=4x, AB and CD are any two parallel chords having slope 1. C1 is a circle passing through O, A and B and C2 is a circle passing through O, C and D, where O is origin. C1 and C2 Intersect at -?

I know that is A(t1) and B(t2) are points on the parabola having slope 1 then t1+t2=2, but i did not get what property is used in the solution where they simply add t1+t2+t5=0 to find the answer. Please view the attached image of the [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nVwf.jpg).

Comment: The solution you linked includes a lot of typos and is hardly readable: please typeset it with MathJax and correct the errors.

Comment: Thank you sir for getting my doubt cleared. Sorry for the errors caused while posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ be the equation of a generic circle.
Plugging there $x=t^2,\ y=2t$ we get the equation for the intersections between circle and parabola:
$$
t^4+(4+2g)t^2+4ft+c=0.
$$
In the case of circle $C_1$ we know this equation has three real solutions $(t_1,t_2,0)$, hence it also has a fourth real solution, let's call it $t_5$. The sum of these solutions is the opposite of the coefficient of $t^3$ in the equation, which in our case is vanishing. Hence:
$$
t_1+t_2+0+t_5=0
$$
and an analogous reasoning can be done for circle $C_2$.